# rstudio ggplot barplot 4 categories, 2 different years , 2 levels to get 1 mean and show in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have been struggeling on a barplot two days now but i really need some help here.
What i need is 4 barplots diagrams besides each other for the four levels of burning degrees in a forest (level 1-4), in each graph i want a distribution of diametres of trees (no.= 9005 trees) with classes from 1(<10cm) to 10(>=50 cm).xlab=classes of diametre (1-10); ylab= number of stems in this diametre class. But i have different numbers of trees for each level so i would need to use the mean for every bar (devide the sum with the number of stems with the same number A03,...)
or group them through the column "class" which already is the diameter class. And last but not least i want to bars next to each other(or one after teh others) for the two periods (2011 and 2020).

no. dbh year          level class
A03  19 2011 unverbrannt        1
A03  19 2011 kaum verbrannt     2
A04  27 2011 kaum verbrannt     3
A04  15 2011 kaum verbrannt     4
A05  33 2011 kaum verbrannt     5
B01  21 2011 kaum verbrannt     6
.     2020 .                    7
2020 kaum verbrannt       8
.     2020 .                    9
.     .    schwach verbrannt   10
.     .
.     .    stark verbrannt

In the end it should look like this:
https://luisdva.github.io/rstats/Diverging-bar-plots/

I hope it makes any sense.

Thanks in advance
Elsa

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. This is my data.
I have:
10 groups diametre distribution classes "BHD klasse"
and 2 time periods (jahr) and i wanne get a graph for each
4 groups degree of burning "grad" ( with ggplot facet wrap maybe):

i just could reproduce or copy the code in here so here is an example:

BHD Klasse     Jahr       grad
1              2011       stark
2              2011       schwach
3              2020       nicht
4              2020       kaum
5              2020       kaum

i tried to use the gplot

```
BHD Klasse     jahr      grad

1              2011      stark
2              2020      schwach
1              2011      kaum
5              2020      stark
10             2020      nicht




ggplot()+ geom_histogram(data=bhdklass,aes(x = bhdklasse, fill=jahr))
```

would be awesome if i´d hear from you

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information instead of providing it as an answer.